# Bug with in-place quick selection (aka linear time selection) in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I am following the Stanford course "Algorithms: Design and Analysis, Part 1", while trying implement an in place randomized selection algorithm in Python (i.e. selection based on quick sort), I believe my partition function is correct, but I just cannot figure out why the selection part keeps failing, any suggestion is greatly appreciated. My code is as follows:

```py
import random
def random_selection(nums, start, end, i):   
    if end == start:
        return nums[start]
    elif start < end:       
        pivot = partition(nums, start, end)        
        if pivot == i:            
            return nums[pivot]
        elif pivot < i:
            # original code suffering from logic error with indices, fixed by changing 'i - pivot' into 'i' 
            # return random_selection(nums, pivot + 1, end, i - pivot)
            return random_selection(nums, pivot + 1, end, i)
        elif pivot > i:
            return random_selection(nums, start, pivot - 1, i)
    else:       
        return False        


def partition(nums, start, end):
    pivot_value = nums[start]
    left = start + 1
    right = end
    done = False
    while not done:
        while left <= right and nums[left] < pivot_value:
            left += 1

        while left <= right and nums[right] > pivot_value:
            right -= 1

        if left > right:
            done = True
        else:
            nums[left], nums[right] = nums[right], nums[left]
    nums[start], nums[right] = nums[right], nums[start]
    return right  

test = range(10)
for i in range(10):
    random.shuffle(test)
    print random_selection(test, 0, len(test)-1, i)
```

Below are the results I am receiving with the test case:

> 0
>    1
>    None
>    3
>    4
>    None
>    5
>    4
>    8
>    None

Comment: what happens if you call random_selection with start > end ?

Comment: @abukaj I added the start > end scenario, thanks for this comment

Comment: @Will: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: @mart0903 not really, it seems that my random_selection function is suffering from logical error. I am still thinking about it.

Comment: @m69 Thanks for the proof reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you need to decide whether your indices are based on 0, or based on start.

Most of the code uses indices based on 0, except the recursive call to random_selection:

```
return random_selection(nums, pivot + 1, end, i - pivot)
```

which adjusts the i index to `i - start` (i.e. assuming the indices are based on start).

Changing this to:

```
return random_selection(nums, pivot + 1, end, i)
```

should give the expected results.